# Using importdata() to automatically change headerlines from file to file

Tags: matlab, loops, file-io, csv, import

Okay so I have multiple files that I'm trying to import for analysis, and I'm using uiimport() to do this within a script currently, but I have to manually shift the headerlines for each file as they change every time.  I would like to do something like this:

```
DELIMITER = ',';
HEADERLINES = 50;  
data_imported = importdata(file_to_get, DELIMITER, HEADERLINES);
```

But the issue is that only 1 or 2 of my 300~ files has a headerline count of 50.  Another very important note, is that the default number of headerlines for EVERY file only needs to have 2 added to it.  So if the default headerline number while using uiimport() is 50, then i would need to change it to 52.

Would there be a way to change this with possibly an if statement? Note: defaultheader is being used as and example and not an actual variable.

for example:

```
if defaultheader = 30
     header = 32
end
```

---

example of what the .CSV file looks like in excel

```
*Title
*
*Description (1.7)   Tue 03/20/12 09:59:09
*
* file name
*
* TestNames:
* _Test 1   (ein: 10)
* _Test 2   (ein: 15)
* _Test 3   (ein: 20)
* _Test 4   (ein: 25)
* _test 5   (ein: 30)
* _test 6   (ein: 35)
* _test 7   (ein: 40)
* _test 8   (ein: 45)
* _test 9   (ein: 50)
* _test 10   (ein: 55)
* _test 11   (ein: 60)
* _test 12   (ein: 65)
* _test 13   (ein: 70)
* _test 14  (ein: 75)
* _test 15   (ein: 80)
* _test 16   (ein: 85)
*
* Info1: ...
* Info2: ...
* info3: ...
* info4: ...
* info5: ...
* info6: ...
* info7: ...
* info8: ...
* info9: ...
* info10: ...
* info11: ...
* info12: ...
*
* Pixel,Tap Name,Tap Pixel,brightness
,,,10,15,20,25,30,35,40
,,,0,67,21,12,223,231,832
1,0A1,458,75,89,24,46,256,763,532
2,0A1,457,43,65,56,554,263,254,732
3,0A1,456,28,47,76,221,412,732,832
4,0A1,455,12,23,36,466,652,633,637
5,0A1,454,11,78,98,678,864,241,223
```

Comment: can you post the first few lines for one of those files (make sure it includes the format of the headers and data rows)?

Comment: I added the rough frame work of the file.  I wasnt able to actually get the main data section to display correctly, but just note it starts after the item column at teh same row.  so for example there would be 20 more columns worth of values that are tied to item 1

Comment: does this mean that all header lines start with a `*` character?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'll ask you to double check the content again and describe the format of the file more thoroughly (for one not all data is numeric, second column seems to be a string not a number). When [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question, use the "format code" button so that it renders correctly. It is important to know the exact format of the file if we are to help parse it... You see it's all in the details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) function to read the CSV files, and specify the `CommentStyle` option to ignore all header lines starting with a `*` character.

The code below will first read the file as a cell array of lines, ignoring all lines starting with `*`. We also skip the first two lines immediately after the header section. Next, we loop over each line, and parse the tab-delimited values as string. We ignore the first three columns, and convert the remaining values to numeric. Finally we store that row in the matrix `M`. Note that the code does not assume we know the number of columns in advance, and instead determine that from one of the data rows.

```
%# read lines
fid = fopen('file.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', ...
    'Delimiter','', 'Whitespace','\n', 'CommentStyle','*');
fclose(fid);
C = C{1}(3:end);    %# skip two lines

%# parse each line
numCols = sum(C{1}==',')+1 - 3;    %# number of columns
M = zeros(numel(C),numCols);
for i=1:numel(C)
    v = textscan(C{i}, '%s', 'Delimiter',',');
    v = str2double(v{1}(4:end));
    M(i,1:numel(v)) = v;
end
```

The resulting matrix `M` containing the part of the file you are interested in:

```
M =
    75    89    24    46   256   763   532
    43    65    56   554   263   254   732
    28    47    76   221   412   732   832
    12    23    36   466   652   633   637
    11    78    98   678   864   241   223
```

Comment: This issue that presents itself here is that, the number of columns also changes from file to file.  But something else to note is that, the first column that contains the data i need is column 4, is there a way to only read from there on?

Comment: @BenB.: to extract from column 4 til end, just do `C(:,4:end)`. As for the non-fixed number of column issue, well it changes things.. You can always read the file line by line and parse those it turn. I'll try to post a new solution

Comment: This is gettign closer to the correct solution,  is there a way to remove the 2 rows after the last * ? as they are not needed as well.  And what looks like is happening currently is, it's creating both the C and M variables, the M variable is a 5450x19 cell but where the data should be in M there are 0s and a couple NaN's i believe this is from the additional 2 rows that could be removed.  While in the C variable, it its producing a 5450x1 double, With all the values that i need.  They are just smushed together into one column and separated by commas.  The correct table should be 5448x17

Comment: also:

would this be an acceptable substitute to your files = dir('*.csv');

file_to_get = uigetfile({'*.csv*'}, 'Select the CSV File', 'folder_path');
fid = fopen(file_to_get, 'rt');

Comment: @BenB.: can you edit your question and re-post the extract from the file as is (say showing headers+5 first rows). Also please make sure to get the formatting right. It is difficult to guess why you get `NaN`/`0`s without seeing the actual data. As for the variables created, you can ignore `C`, it was a created in an intermediate step, and contains the file lines (un-separated). The matrix `M` should contain the numeric result. Finally, `dir` or `uigetfile` should be fine.

Comment: This is as close to the original formatting as i could get it.  The two rows above the row starting with 1 0A1 are the ones that can be removed.  I was receving 6 NaN's in the result before and why i think this is happening is due to the 6 words in the final row starting with *Pixel tap name tap pixel brightness

Comment: also: this does not include all the columns from the dataset, but we already discussed that they change from file to file anyway. The first 3 columns where the data starts are also unneeded: 1 0A1 458.  The numbers in bold are the actual needed values

Comment: @BenB.: please see my latest edit, this should solve all the problems

Comment: Now the Variable M is completely empty.  However, it is telling me that M is now a <5448x0 double> and i know you said i could ignore it but the data in C is actually starting at the correct Row.

Comment: @BenB.: I was assuming the data is tab-delimited `\t`, is that the case or is it space delimited?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it more clear that they are CSV files.  I have updated my question with their rawest form with no spacing and commas in place.

Comment: @BenB.: The sample you posted in your question did not show that... this is why I previously asked you to describe the file format exactly. Next time please be thorough and state all relevant details up-front :( Anyway I fixed the code, and it correctly works on that sample posted

Comment: Seriously thank you. Only having a single GUI now for the file select is so much faster.  And having a couple others look at the data and code firsthand with no success, makes your help so much more appreciated.